# error while loading shared libraries, installation misplaced `.so` files in /usr/lib

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, libevent

I'm using libevent in my source code, after compiling the program, I run it and I got the following error:

```
./my_program: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-1.4.so.2: cannot open shared
```

previously I was at a loss on how to instal libevent and  installed something like `libverto-libevent-0.2.5-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm`. Anyway, finally I compiled and installed the libevent source code by `./configure, make and make install`, but it was installed in `/usr/lib` while `/usr/lib64` is occupied by previous residue .so files, as below:

```
    [esolve@kity lib]$ ls /usr/lib64|grep "libevent"
    libevent-2.0.so.5
    libevent-2.0.so.5.0.1
    libevent_core-2.0.so.5
    libevent_core-2.0.so.5.0.1
    libevent_extra-2.0.so.5
    libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.0.1
    libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5
    libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.0.1
    libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5
    libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.0.1
    libeventviews.so.4
    libeventviews.so.4.8.0

    [esolve@kity lib]$ ls /usr/lib|grep "libevent"
    libevent-1.4.so.2
    libevent-1.4.so.2.2.0
    libevent.a
    libevent_core-1.4.so.2
    libevent_core-1.4.so.2.2.0
    libevent_core.a
    libevent_core.la
    libevent_core.so
    libevent_extra-1.4.so.2
    libevent_extra-1.4.so.2.2.0
    libevent_extra.a
    libevent_extra.la
    libevent_extra.so
    libevent.la
    libevent.so
    [esolve@kity lib]$
```

what can I do so I can run ./my_program successfully?
my system is fedora 16, I want to link to `libevent-1.4.so`
thanks!

BTW:

I tried to rpm -e all previously-wrongly-installed rpm package, there are some "the package is not installed" prompts, and I got

```
    [esolve@kity lib]$ ls /usr/lib64|grep "libevent"
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       21 Apr  3  2012 libevent-2.0.so.5 -> libevent-2.0.so.5.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   280720 Feb  9  2011 libevent-2.0.so.5.0.1
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       26 Apr  3  2012 libevent_core-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_core-2.0.so.5.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   165760 Feb  9  2011 libevent_core-2.0.so.5.0.1
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       27 Apr  3  2012 libevent_extra-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   127400 Feb  9  2011 libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.0.1
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       29 Apr  3  2012 libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root    21352 Feb  9  2011 libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.0.1
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       30 Apr  3  2012 libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5 -> libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root     6992 Feb  9  2011 libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.0.1
    lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root       22 Jul 31  2012 libeventviews.so.4 -> libeventviews.so.4.8.0
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   974656 Jul  9  2012 libeventviews.so.4.8.0
```

Comment: Can't you just uninstall the RPM you don't want?

Comment: Did you try to add the path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `export` ?

Comment: What OS is this, and which version of libevent do you want to link to?

Comment: did you call ldconfig as root?

Comment: what is ldconfig used for in this case?

Comment: @ultima_rat0  I'm not familiar with compiling. so which one is the default library directary? /usr/lib or /usr/lib64?  I hope I can compile my source code with default library directory.

Comment: I don't have a 64bit computer here, but it looks like this is a default directory. `ldconfig -p` for printing the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Libraries installed from source you have to run ldconfig, packagemanagers do this for you. But if you build a library from source you have to run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

but also

```
ldconfig
```

and both `make install` and `ldconfig` should be done as superuser

```
man ldconfig
```

can tell you way more about caching and updating the libraries then I can.

Comment: BTW, can I remove all the `.so` files in /usr/lib64 which are related to libevent? because I only need libevent-1.4.so

Comment: I believe ldconfig tells the linker where to find the libraries and does some other stuff, but see the manpages. I'm puzzeled by the fact that your libraries ended up in /usr/lib I would have expected them in /usr/local/lib unless you specified somting strange to the prefix variable while configuring/installing.

Comment: ah, I did something like: ./configure –prefix=/usr, I also want to use `gcc -m32 -o` for compiling my program, my machine is x86_64. what libevent libraries should I install. and will the `/usr/lib` affect the 32-bit version of the libevent library?

Comment: @user138126 I would say run make uninstall as root and configure you program at let the configure script do the work for you because then the prefix will default to /usr/local build it again install it again. Don't forget ldconfig aswell cheers and goodnight.

Answer (score 0):

can't u remove the libevent 2.0?

you can use rpm -e in rpm method.

or, in your Makefile you can link the libevent-2.0 rather than libevent-1.4.

Comment: this is not a question, but a suggestion